# Change admin password in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla ! (2.5...)
I would like to change the administrator password.

Naturally I chose the 'modify account' option of the admin, got the form, changed the password and confirmation and recorded : suddenly a lot of PHP warnings appeared (null given and other insults)..

well it did not work .

So ? How do you change admin password in fact ?

Thank you

Comment: The steps for password change are correct. The warnings could be from another php error, please check your error_log to find the exact problem.

Comment: In the log : the name of the user does not fit the password or you dont have an account... what does that mean ?

Comment: I am not sure, is your joomla updated to the latest version?

Comment: maybe not, this is a project already written.. is there a way to know the version of joomla ?

Comment: it's under: System -> System Information -> Joomla! Version.

Comment: I meant inside the project (file system)... what is the System you are talking about ?